# Alert box not show when sign up has same username

Tags: php, html

I am doing my a sign up using php, I want to show up an alert box that show "User already taken". However when I sign up an account that have same information like the last account, it's not show an alert box. It will go back to blank login page like I set it. The data duplicate not write to the mySQL but the alert box not show. 
Thanks

```
<?php

session_start();
header('location:login.php');
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','');

mysqli_select_db($con, 'userregistration');

$name = $_POST['user'];
$pass = $_POST ['password'];
$email = $_POST['mail'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];

$s = " SELECT * FROM usertable WHERE name = '$name'";

$result = mysqli_query($con, $s);

$num = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if ($num == 1){
    $message="User already taken";
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'> alert('$message');</script>";
}else {
    $reg = "INSERT INTO usertable(name, password, email, phone ) values ('$name', '$pass','$email', '$phone')";/*, '$email','$phone'*/
    mysqli_query($con, $reg);
    echo"Registration successfull";
}
?>
```

Comment: In case you prevented the page from showing more alerts, try appending your message after your `script` tag and see if the message shows up. Also, your code is vulnerable to SQL injections

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to check for successful connection/query first:

```
if($result=mysqli_query($con,$s)) {
   if(mysqli_num_rows($result)==1) { 
         ... user already taken code ... 
   } else { 
         ... insert new user code ... 
   }
}
```

See w3schools ref: https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_num_rows.asp

This may also help you debug where the problem is occurring.